# rails - development database is not configured

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine

I am trying to set up redmine and have created a stupid simple database.yml as follows:

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

When I run `rake db:create` it creates the development database as expected. However, when I run `rake db:migrate` it fails saying:

```
development database is not configured!
```

Why can I not run `db:migrate` if `database.yml` is configured correctly enough to create the database?

**EDIT:**

I ran `RAILS_ENV=development rake db:migrate` and got the following error message:

```
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/mail-2.4.4.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2012-03-14 00:00:00.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/tilt-1.3.3.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-08-25 00:00:00.000000000Z"
NOTE: SourceIndex.new(hash) is deprecated; From /usr/share/redmine/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:100 in `new'.
rake aborted!
ERROR: 'rake/rdoctask' is obsolete and no longer supported. Use 'rdoc/task' (available in RDoc 2.4.2+) instead.
```

Answer (score 4):

try to run

```
RAILS_ENV=development rake db:migrate
```

Also you can run rake task with --trace to figure out problem

Answer (score 2):

Check `config/environment.rb` for what mode you are running as. If memory serves, redmine runs in production mode by default.